# On each login --- startup or new terminal session --- a folder named `~` is created in my home folder

Tags: bash, macos, shell, session

I am running OSX High Sierra with Homebrew.

Since yesterday, restarting the computer or creating a new login session - opening a terminal window, say - creates a `~`-named folder in my home directory if it does not already exist.

I imagine there is a `if (~ does not exist): mkdir /Users/me/~` type of call on creating a new session but are at a loss where to look.

I have checked logs via /Applications/Utilities/Console but have not found anything helpful yet.

**Bash** is my default shell. I also use the **fish** shell and the `~` folder is also created when starting a fish session.

The existence of the `~` folder within my home folder is causing issues with pyenv where calling `pyenv versions` displays only my system python, not any of the pyenv installed python versions nor any created virtual environments.

I have nothing in my `.bash_profile` nor `.bashrc` that would create these and so wish to find just what file is being read that creates the offending folder.

Comment: Since bash and fish using different startup files, and since this, as you say, happens already after starting the computer (i.e. without you opening a terminal window), I don't think it is related to your startup files. You could have a look at /etc/profile, though I doubt that you find something there. Did you update your MacOS just before the problem appeared for the first time? What does a `ls -l` of this file say?

Comment: As a hack, you could of course do a `rm $HOME/~ 2>/dev/null` in your `.bash_profile`, but of course it would be good to know where this strange file comes in the first place.

Comment: I'll try restarting the computer after posting this comment. For now I have my pyenv installed versions back after changing the line `export PYENV_ROOT="~/.pyenv"` to `export PYENV_ROOT="/Users/me/.pyenv"`. This has not been changed recently and it had not caused issues before so I'm assuming that a recent update from Homebrew may have altered the way the tilda `~` is interpreted. I'm not certain. Anyway, I will now reboot and see if the offending folder is re-created on startup.

Comment: The tilda folder is not being created during restarting the computer nor on creating a terminal session. I've solved my problem of not having access to python virtual environments but am still in the dark as to what change in my system could have caused the tilda to be misread in an `EXPORT` statement. I have read warnings in the past to only use expanded paths.

Comment: Well, `PYENV_ROOT="~/.pyenv"` doesn't make sense, because the tilde would not be expanded by bash to your home directory, so whichever program is using this environment variable, would have to do the expansion. It's not obvious that pyenv is doing it. I would write the line as `export PYENV_ROOT=$HOME/.pyenv`.

Comment: What does `ls -l ~` yield? Perhaps owning user and group will shed some light on this. Are you sure it doesn't exist before launching terminal? I'd also try setting different default shells like `zsh` or `sh` to narrow down the problem. Do you experience the same as the root user?

Answer (score 0):

I had been playing around with `for` loops in the **fish** shell and a typo created the `~` folder in the home directory.

Expanding all EXPORT statements in my profile files (`.bashrc, .bash_profile, .bash_alias`) stopped this from reoccurring.

e.g. `EXPORT PATH="~/bin:$PATH"` to `EXPORT PATH="/Users/me/bin:$PATH"`

I could have also used `EXPORT PATH="HOME/bin:$PATH"`